# is-my-json-valid plugin compare with exact value issue

Tags: node.js

I use [is-my-json-valid](https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid) plugin for nodeJS and I wonder if there any pattern to validate if integer is same integer and string is the same string.

So far I found the way to do that as:

Input JSON:

```
const body = {            
        exactInteger: 20,
        exactString: "snaggs"
    };
```

Schema:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {    
    "exactInteger"   : {"type" : "integer", "minimum" : 20, "maximum" : 20, "required": true},
    "exactString"    : {"type" : "string", "pattern": "^snaggs$", "required": true}
  }
}
```

but it looks complicated, any other way?

Answer (score -2):

There is a node module called [node-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-validator), which is close to meet your expectation. The above module helps you to get the values.
But you have to write a custom function for validating against a specific value.

*For e.g: validating against a number:*

```
validator.isNumber({min: 75, max: 76});
```

- `min` - Minimum value of the integer
- `max` - Maximum value of the integer

Comment: @bfontaine The answer is npm itself. The OP expects a module. The link would be there as long as the module exists and the module is quite famous.

Comment: @HariPrasad Wait until you have sufficient reputation then post a comment if you just want to give a link to a module. OP has a specific question; just throwing a link to an npm module doesn’t answer it; you need to explain how it can solves the original question. Also, FYI the maintenance of this module stopped 5 months ago.